# mysql return people with similar purchase and desc order by count of similar items

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

customers table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |

purchase table

| product_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| y | 1 |
| x | 4 |
| y | 4 |
| x | 3 |
| z | 2 |

the customer table has customer data and purchase table has order data.
Now coming to question, I want customers id who bought similar products ordered by the count of similar items
eg:
if i want customers who bought similar items like customer 'a'
the query should return

| customer_id | similar items count |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

'a' bought x,y
d' bought x,y,
c' bought x

so d and c should be returned order by similar items count (desc)

i am not good at larger sql queries, so i need to ask this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM purchase t1
JOIN purchase t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
                AND t1.customer_id < t2.customer_id
GROUP BY t1.customer_id, t2.customer_id;
```

will return customers pair and the amount of similar products for them.